# numbers into group?

Tags: mysql, sql

In the database table, I have about 1 million record.

In the `number` field  there are about 11 digits number.

If the 5 digit number is the same, I want to group it so I can export it later.

How to archive this?

For example:

```
077129342480

074545344535

077127777476

077126565656

074546546654
```

You can see there are two group of number which are 07712 and 07454

In the `group` field I could declare the group name in number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `GROUP BY SUBSTR(number, 1, 5)` or `GROUP BY LEFT(number, 5)`.

Comment: Ahh I didnt thought of that, thanks. What about group field (Groupnumber)? UPDATE SET Groupnumber = '' while doing  `GROUP BY SUBSTR(number, 1, 5)` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
select SUBSTR(number, 1, 5) Groupnumber, number
from yourtable
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select LEFT(data, 5) Groupnumber, count(id)
from test
group by Groupnumber;
```